# Trouble with Youtube API, NodeJS, and Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, promise, bluebird

I am struggling mightily with one part of a project I am working on in Node. I started using Node for the first time a few weeks ago so I am very newbish to it, and I am not very experienced in coding in general.

I have a library called video.js where I want to get a list of videos of a specific playlist.

I have a prototype function that is called in the controller called getVideoList, which gets the id of the playlist along with some other information and then does an API call to youtube and gets results.

If there are more results than 50, then in the response there will be a nextPageToken property. If there is one, then I would have to do the API call again so that I get the next page of results. (I don't think its possible to get all video objects in one API call.)

An example of what happens:

```
code starts

first loop finishes

promise fulfilled

second loop starts

second loop finishes


...

meanwhile the rest of the code is already moving along to the next function (that needs to have the second loops results added to the data videolist)
```

As of now, this code does the first API call fine, and pushes the dataObj into the videoList. The promise is fulfilled before the rest of the loop is being completed. If I take the fulfill(videoList) out of the first part of the if statement, then the promise isn't fulfilled at all.

I have been doing a lot of reading and it looks like Bluebird might be the right way to go, but this is the only part of my code that isn't working right now and I don't know if it is necessary or not, and if it is, I am confused on how to implement it in this scenario.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Videos.prototype.getVideoList = function(playlistInfo) {

var playlistId = playlistInfo.playlistId;

var videoList = [];
getVideos = function(playlistId, apiKey, nextPageToken) {
    var playlistOptions = {
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=" + playlistId +  apiKey,
            method: 'GET'
    };
    if (nextPageToken) {
        playlistOptions.url = playlistOptions.url + '&pageToken=' + nextPageToken
    }

    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
        request(playlistOptions, function(error, results, body){
            if (error) { reject(error); };

            var result = JSON.parse(body);
            for(var i = 0; i < result.items.length; i++){
                    var dataObj = {};
                    dataObj.videoId = result.items[i].contentDetails.videoId;
                    dataObj.title = result.items[i].snippet.title;
                    if (result.items[i].snippet.thumbnails) {
                        dataObj.thumbnail = result.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
                    };
                    videoList.push(dataObj);
            };
            if (result.nextPageToken){
                getVideos(playlistId, apiKey, result.nextPageToken);
                fulfill(videoList);
            } else {
                fulfill(videoList);
            }
        })

    });

}
return getVideos(this.videoTotal, playlistId, this.apiKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Promise A+ compliant library (such as Bluebird) you can resolve any promise with another promise.   In your case, the solution might be as simple as:

```
if (result.nextPageToken){
    fulfill(getVideos(playlistId, apiKey, result.nextPageToken));
} else {
    fulfill(videoList);
}
```

Instead of resolving the videoList right away on the first page, the resolution becomes the results from the next page (when they become available), which will be resolved by the results from the page after that... etc, until you hit a page with no PageToken and the whole chain is resolved as complete videoList.